# Borrar información de Textbox en un formulario C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Compañeros estoy desarrollando un proyecto en ASP.NET dónde tengo mis Textbox y un botón de enviar datos, lo que quiero hacer es, cuando el usuario envie la información se limpien los textbox de manera automatica creo que se podría decir, sin tener un botón de limpiar, ya que he visto tutoriales con ese botón pero no lo quiero así.
¿Cómo se podrá hacer esto?

He intentado con esto:

```
     txtnombre.Text = "";
```

pero algunos campos del formulario no los tengo en la base de datos ya que no los necesito y me marca error, solamente no me marca error cuando si los tengo en mi base de datos

Comment: Hola Marth, ¿será posible que incluyas secciones de código de los intentos o avances que hayas realizado? Con eso, te podríamos dar una guía más a detalle del problema que presentas.

Comment: y porque no utilizar la misma funcionalidad que viste en el boton de limpiar, luego de presionar el boton de enviar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tratándose de un `TextBox` de ASP.Net y al intentar realizar `txtnombre = "";`, estás intentando igualar un objeto de tipo `TextBox` a `string`, lo cual te va a generar un error. La propiedad `Text` es la que almacena el contenido del texto, por lo tanto, lo podrás limpiar de la siguente forma en conjunto con un `string.empty`:

```
txtnombre.Text = string.empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que estas hablando de una app de Escritorio. Podrías hacer una función que limpie los elementos de tu forma como se describe aquí:

[EmptyTextBoxes](http://www.tek-tips.com/faqs.cfm?fid=6470)

Answer (score 0):

```
txtnombre.Text = string.empty;
```